# open (not run) and edit a R script from Rstudio console

Tags: r, rstudio

Is it possible to open (not run using source) a R script for editing from the console of R studio or R command line

Answer (score 13):

This  is a nice command to edit an r script:

```
file.edit('foo.R')
```

Answer (score 7):

You can open a file for editing with `edit`, e.g.,

```
edit(file = "test.R")
```

See `help("edit")` for more information, in particular regarding different editors.

Comment: Worth noting that the edit() function uses vim as default when run through Linux terminal. Hence vim key-chains apply: press "i" to edit; "<esc> : x" to quit and save; and "<esc> : q !" to quit without saving.

Answer (score 2):

You could just read it like a text file and do anything you want with it. This can be done using the following syntax

```
SourceF <- file("Source.R", open = "r")
SourceF_lines <- readLines(SourceF)
```

To follow with someting like:

```
cat(SourceF_lines, sep = "\n")
## or
writeClipboard(SourceF_lines)
```

Or replace a specific part:

```
SourceF_lines[2] <- '## Do not run!!'
```